# Getting all response headers from an api request. Currently not all available

Tags: javascript, httpresponse

I have an http request where I want some response headers that are, for one reason or another, unavailable to me from the response object but visible in the chrome dev tools
[image]

But the response object from the javascript `request` api only contains some of these headers.

```
{ // response.headers
  cache-control: "no-cache, private",
  content-type: "application/json"
}
```

Surely, there must be a way to get things like `x-ratelimit-limit` as part of the response. If it's information sent to the browser, why can't it be available in a javascript http request api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a CORS request. If so, response headers *are* restricted unless the right `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header is set. This is for security reasons.

Comment: This was the answer I was hoping to not find. Attempting to add `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` responds with: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. This is a public api. Does that mean the other headers are fundamentally inaccessible?

Comment: @Andrew if you don't have control over the service, then your only option is to set up your own service and proxy the public service you're trying to access.